# MS Dynamics 2011 Workflow "emails are not sending"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm recieving the following error message in MS Dynamics 2011: "This message cannot be sent to all selected recipients. Verify that both the sender and the recipients have valid email addresses, and that the recipients are allowed to recieve emails" However, I already verified that all the email addresses are valid. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're emailing Contact records.

If so, make sure that the contact preferences are set to Allow for Email (see screenshot below)

[image: Contact Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by making sure the contact had an email address and verified 'Allow Email' field.

After that it worked.